# Есть поток в котором хранится дата. Вопрос, как отфильтровать все даты имеющие в своем составе на второй позиции с конца цифру кратную 3?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1970,Month.JANUARY,1);
      LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();

//      Stream<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.plusDays(1))
//                                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end));
     Stream<LocalDate> dates = LongStream
    .rangeClosed(0, LocalDate.now().toEpochDay())
    .mapToObj(LocalDate::ofEpochDay);
     for (Integer i : dates){ //error
         System.out.println(i % 3 == 0);
     }
        System.out.println(dates);

    }
```

Comment: Что значит _на второй позиции с конца_? В дне или в году? Или ещё где-то?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, в году, прошу прощения

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отфильтровать поток (если не нужно считать *0* кратным *3*, нужно будет добавить ещё один фильтр):

```
LongStream
    .rangeClosed(0, LocalDate.now().toEpochDay())
    .mapToObj(LocalDate::ofEpochDay)
    .filter(d -> d.getYear() / 10 % 10 % 3 == 0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```